# How to find the index of the last occurrence of nested list that contains a specific element?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I need to (eventually) insert a value in a specific place in a nested list, but it needs to be inserted after the last occurrence of a specific string in the nested list...So I need to first find the index of this last occurrence. Might make more sense with an example (I will generalize):

```
a = 'RPGAccount'

input = [['RPGAccount', 'ddi=0', 'pp=0', 'kol=0', 'sddf=1234567890', '4233f2dsfa=abc', 'igg=dev1', 'id=4g43g34b433435n35n'], ['RPGAccount', 'ddi=0', 'pp=0', 'kol=0', 'sddf=NA', '4233f2dsfa=abc', 'igg=source', 'id=4g43g34b433435n35n'], ['RPGAdditional', 'addkey=asdf', 'addvalue=false', '4233f2dsfa=abc', 'igg=dev1', 'id=4g43g34b433435n35n', 'tz=asdf'], ['RPGAdditional', 'addkey=device_id', 'addvalue=F309387C-AAF5-478D-95A2-28E9B46105C7', '4233f2dsfa=abc', 'igg=dev1', 'id=4g43g34b433435n35n', 'tz=asdf'], ['RPGAdditional', 'addkey=sdaf', 'addvalue=fixed_ap', '4233f2dsfa=abc', 'igg=dev1', 'id=4g43g34b433435n35n', 'tz=asdf’]]

b = 1
```

So I need to have an index of 1 returned, since 1 is the index of the list

```
['RPGAccount', 'ddi=0', 'pp=0', 'kol=0', 'sddf=NA', '4233f2dsfa=abc', 'igg=source', 'id=4g43g34b433435n35n']
```

which contains the last occurrence of the string 'RPGAccount'

I know I should be doing something like:

```
for l in input:
    for l_ in l:
        if a in l_:
            print input.index[l]
        else:
            pass
```

Solution:

```
some_list = []
for l in input:
    for l_ in l:
        if a in l_:
            some_list.append(input.index(l))
        else:
            pass
location_ = some_list[-1]
print location_
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that like this:

```
a = 'RPGAccount'
input = [['RPGAccount', 'ddi=0', 'pp=0', 'kol=0', 'sddf=1234567890', '4233f2dsfa=abc', 'igg=dev1', 'id=4g43g34b433435n35n'],
         ['RPGAccount', 'ddi=0', 'pp=0', 'kol=0', 'sddf=NA', '4233f2dsfa=abc', 'igg=source', 'id=4g43g34b433435n35n'],
         ['RPGAdditional', 'addkey=asdf', 'addvalue=false', '4233f2dsfa=abc', 'igg=dev1', 'id=4g43g34b433435n35n', 'tz=asdf'],
         ['RPGAdditional', 'addkey=device_id', 'addvalue=F309387C-AAF5-478D-95A2-28E9B46105C7', '4233f2dsfa=abc', 'igg=dev1', 'id=4g43g34b433435n35n', 'tz=asdf'],
         ['RPGAdditional', 'addkey=sdaf', 'addvalue=fixed_ap', '4233f2dsfa=abc', 'igg=dev1', 'id=4g43g34b433435n35n', 'tz=asdf']]
# Index of last sublist containing a - if not found returns -1
b = next((len(input) - i - 1 for i, lst in enumerate(reversed(input)) if a in lst), -1)
print(b)
# 1
```

Using your loop, it would be more efficient to do as follows:

```
location_ = -1
for i, l in enumerate(input):
    for l_ in l:
        if a in l_:
            location_ = i
print location_
# 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, mistake was small and I resolved it...

```
some_list = []
for l in input:
    for l_ in l:
        if a in l_:
            some_list.append(input.index(l))
        else:
            pass
location_ = some_list[-1]
print location_
```